# Signing a valid ERC20 transfer transaction

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js, evm, sendtransaction, ethers.rs

I'm building a backend that has an endpoint to set up a send transaction. This send can be a native, ERC20, ERC721, or ERC1155. The idea is to configure the transaction correctly according to its type, and after, sign and send. For now I can set up a native send transaction and send it to the blobkchain but for ERC20 send I can set up the transaction send to a chain without error but the transfer doesn't work, [example of my ERC20 send on explorer](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xd40ea73f61bd832549632b18b3836f6b1b69c4587875fb364b6dcc138babb3ec).

Can you identify any errors in the way that I set up this transaction? I'm using rust with ethers 2.0.7.

```
let tx_request = match transaction_type {
TransactionType::Send => {
    let value_wei = parse_ether(&value.unwrap_or_default())
        .map_err(|err| BaseError::UnexpectedError(err.into()))?;

    let to_address: Address = H160::from_str(to_address.unwrap_or_default().as_str())
        .map_err(|err| BaseError::UnexpectedError(err.into()))?
        .into();

    TransactionRequest::new()
        .from(from_address)
        .to(to_address)
        .value(value_wei)
        .nonce(nonce)
        .gas_price(gas_price)
}
TransactionType::SendERC20 => match validate_erc20_fields(&query_clone) {
    Ok((to_address, value, token_address)) => {
        let value = U256::from_str(value.as_str()).unwrap_or(U256::zero());

        let contract_address: Address = Address::from_str(token_address.as_str())
            .map_err(|err| BaseError::UnexpectedError(err.into()))?;

        abigen!(ERC20Token, "src/routes/transaction/ERC20ABI.json",);

        let provider_clone = provider.clone();
        let provider_arc = Arc::new(provider_clone);
        let erc20_contract = ERC20Token::new(contract_address, provider_arc);

        let to_address: Address = H160::from_str(to_address.as_str())
            .map_err(|err| BaseError::UnexpectedError(err.into()))?
            .into();

        let call: FunctionCall<
            Arc<ethers::providers::Provider<Http>>,
            ethers::providers::Provider<Http>,
            bool,
        > = erc20_contract.transfer(to_address, value);
        
        let data = call.tx.data().unwrap();

        TransactionRequest::new()
            .from(from_address)
            .to(contract_address)
            .data(data.clone())
            .nonce(nonce)
            .value(0)
            .gas_price(gas_price)
    }
    Err(e) => {
        return Err(BaseError::ValidationError(e.to_string()));
    }
},
TransactionType::SendERC721 => {
   // Setup a ERC721 transaction
},
TransactionType::SendERC1155 => {
   // Setup a ERC1155 transaction
},
```

};

Signing is performed on the frontend with ethers.js 6.2.0:

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(
  'https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/apikey'
);

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
  'private key',
  provider
);

const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(ctx.transaction as TransactionRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The problem was that I was sending the value of the `to` field as the address of the user I wanted to transfer the tokens, and the address to be passed in the `to` should be the address of the ERC20 contract